# Syntax error in netplan.yaml after adding wifi section

Tags: netplan

I have a working netplan yaml to which I am trying to add a wifi entry for a second interface. This is an experiment, not an operational requirement.

There is an issue with the syntax of the file. I can see nothing wrong with the identified location in the file. I have no tabs or other non alphanumerics. Here's the situation. I have marked the problematic position in the file:

```
netplan generate
....
Error in network definition /etc/netplan/01-netplan.yaml line 19 column 23: expected mapping
```

Here is the yaml

```
 network:
   version: 2
   ethernets:
     enp0s3:
       addresses: [192.168.0.123/24]
       gateway4: 192.168.0.1
       nameservers:
         search: [*******]
         addresses: [192.168.0.110]
     enp0s8:
       addresses: [192.168.56.123/24]
   wifis:
     usbwifi01:
       addresses: [192.168.0.127/24]
       gateway4: 192.168.0.1
       nameservers:
         search: [*******]
         addresses: [192.168.0.110] 
       access-points:   (first char 'a' is line 19 col 23)      
         "********":
         password: "********"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consult:

```
cat /usr/share/doc/netplan.io/examples/wireless.yaml
```

You have omitted the line:

```
renderer: networkd
```

Also, the letter a in *access-points* in the example is at column 7. I don't see how yours could be at column 23.

Please recheck the spacing in the entire file.

Comment: The renderer line is not required if it is networkd, but I added it anyway. It made no difference. My goof on the column number: I was misreading the geany status line. The position of the 'a' is 6. Col 23 is 3 spaces after the colon at the end of that line  i.e. empty spaces. Once I deleted those spaces, the file passes. Thanks